# node.js, callback on the end of an http-proxy request?

Tags: node.js, proxy

I'm trying to learn node.js, and my context is the http-proxy module from nodejitsu.

I'd like to get access to the end of the proxy event, so that I can log how long the target server took to respond. However, I can't out how to create the appropriate callback or event handler. I've looked at the source for http-proxy, and it doesn't seem to take the conventional callback method.

Here's a sample, I'm sure its a simple fix to someone that breaths Node:

```
/* demonstrate a basic proxy server that can log the time 
it takes to execute a given hit on the destination server
*/
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

// Create the proxy server
httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy) {
    var startTime = ( new Date()).getTime();

    // NEED HELP HERE. 
    // something like this should do it?
    proxy.addListener("end",function() {
        var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        console.log("request took " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");
    });

    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 9000
    });
}).listen(8000);

// the destination server
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.write('request successfully proxied: ' + req.url +'\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
    // make the hit slow by pausing the end()
    setTimeout(function() {
        res.end();
    },2000);
}).listen(9000);
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to intercept the res.end() call. I have like 3 days of express experience, so I don't know what this will screw up:

```
var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();
app.get("/foo", function (req, res) {
    var realEnd = res.end;
    var start = +new Date();
    res.end = function () {
        var elapsed = +new Date() - start;
        console.log("elapsed", elapsed);
        realEnd.apply(res);
    }
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 9000
    });
});
```